# Entity bean not enhanced error when deploying cxf soap war file to weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: maven, cxf, ebean

I created two Entity Beans that will insert user data to a mysql database when a user logs in and when a user is billed. I decided to use Ebean ORM since, it's "lighweight" for just a table insert.

The application is a maven based soap cxf war deployed to a  weblogic 12.2.1 app server and developed on eclipse 2019-06-R xxx.

The unit tests are working correctly in that data is inserted to the test database, the code is also persisting to the normal database when executed in a main class in eclipse and I don't get this "bean not enhanced error..." locally

However the generated war fails with "bean not enhanced error..." after a connection to the database is established (based on the logs) at the point where the insert method of the bean is called.

how can I resolve this?

Based on the official website of Ebean,I followed this tutorial from the setup to the eclipse and maven configurations:

1. https://ebean.io/docs/getting-started/maven
2. https://ebean.io/docs/setup/eclipse-apt
3. https://ebean.io/docs/setup/enhancement
4. https://ebean.io/docs/trouble-shooting

Previous questions are mostly directed to Play framework, which doesn't talk to my problem e.g:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/gdgGGVd0K5E

I've updated my pom.xml, application.yml and ebean.mf  as shown on github examples:

https://github.com/ebean-orm/examples/tree/master/base-example

ran mvn clean install in commandline and redeployed but still getting the same even though locally on unit tests and java main class, data is being inserted to the database

Install and enabled the Ebean Enhacer 11.x plugin

eclipse log:

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:46.453
!MESSAGE ebean v11+ manifest packages - entity: [registration.audit.model] transactional: [] querybean: [registration.audit.model]

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:48.990
!MESSAGE ... enhanceDebugLevel:1

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.014
!MESSAGE ... found ebean manifest file

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.024
!MESSAGE ebean v11+ manifest packages - entity: [registration.audit.model] transactional: [] querybean: [registration.audit.model,registration.audit.model]

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.038
!MESSAGE ... ebean-enhance> cls: registration/audit/model/Bill  msg: enhanced

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.053
!MESSAGE enhanced: registration/audit/model/Bill

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.059
!MESSAGE ... ebean-enhance> cls: registration/audit/model/Login  msg: enhanced

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.repaint.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <tiles>
            <tile>org.avaje.tile:java-compile:1.1</tile>
            <tile>io.ebean.tile:enhancement:11.39.1</tile>
        </tiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.ebean</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebean</artifactId>
    <version>11.38.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- support for query beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.ebean</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebean-querybean</artifactId>
    <version>11.38.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- java annotation processor to generate query beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.ebean</groupId>
    <artifactId>querybean-generator</artifactId>
    <version>11.38.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

ebean.mf:

```
entity-packages: za.gov.deeds.registration.audit.model
transactional-packages: za.gov.deeds.registration.service.audit
querybean-packages: za.gov.deeds.registration.service.audit
profile-location: true
```

application.yml:

```
datasource:
  db:
    username: xxxx
    password: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dbName: db
```

Bill .java:

```java
package registration.audit.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import io.ebean.Model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "soap_user_billing")
public class Bill extends Model {
   ...
}
```

Login .java:

```
package registration.audit.model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "login")

public class Login {
   ....
}
```

Login .java:

```
package registration.service.audit;

public class AuditService {

public  void insertLoginAuditDetails(Login loginAuditBean) throws Exception {

EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(getDBServerConfig());

log.info("DB Server: {}, ", server.getName());

server.insert(loginAuditBean);
```

When the database is offline, EbeanServer throws a connection related error which is 100% but when the database is turned on a "Login bean is not enhanced error" is thrown eventhough eclipse logs show the below:

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.024
!MESSAGE ebean v11+ manifest packages - entity: [registration.audit.model] transactional: [] querybean: [registration.audit.model,registration.audit.model]

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.038
!MESSAGE ... ebean-enhance> cls: registration/audit/model/Bill  msg: enhanced

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.053
!MESSAGE enhanced: registration/audit/model/Bill

!ENTRY io.ebean.eclipse.enhancer 1 0 2019-06-26 10:44:49.059
!MESSAGE ... ebean-enhance> cls: registration/audit/model/Login  msg: enhanced

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by the following editing the mvn pom.xml file as stipulated below:

1. I removed the whole tiles-maven-plugin artifact plugin section outside  to a seperate  sections beneath "", as shown below:

```
 <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>io.repaint.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <tiles>
                <tile>org.avaje.tile:java-compile:1.1</tile>
                <tile>io.ebean.tile:enhancement:11.38.1</tile>
            </tiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

to the below, outside pluginmanagement:

```
<plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.repaint.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <tiles>
                <tile>org.avaje.tile:java-compile:1.1</tile>
                <tile>io.ebean.tile:enhancement:11.38.1</tile>
            </tiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>   
</plugins>
```

Then I ran "mvn clean install" and deployed to weblogic 12.2 with no problem.